# Why is my iPhone 4S's home button not responding from home screen?

Tags: ios, iphone

My home button seems to be working okay to move out of apps etc, and double tapping brings up the expected menu, but on the home page, a single tap no longer swaps to the search interface, and when modifying app positions, clicking home no longer stops the apps 'shaking' - is there any way to rectify this?

Answer (score 1):

These features should definitely work with the home button on your 4S. You should contact Apple to get a solution, which may include repairing or replacing the phone. If you are near an Apple retail store, [set up a genius bar reservation](http://www.apple.com/retail/geniusbar/). If not, [call Apple](http://www.apple.com/support/contact/) for support.